Can I create new features from a matrix?
I'd like to create features from an ispline in tidymodels.  One way to do this would be to use step_mutate as follows:
library(tidymodels)
library(tidyverse)
library(splines2)

data <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 10, 0.1))


rec <- recipe(.~x, data=data) %>% 
  step_mutate(
    model.matrix(~isp(x, df=5))
  ) %>% 
  prep()



bake(rec, new_data = data)
#> # A tibble: 101 × 2
#>        x model.matrix(~isp(x, df = 5…¹ [,"isp(x, df = 5)1"] [,"isp(x, df = 5)2"]
#>    <dbl>                         <dbl>                <dbl>                <dbl>
#>  1   0                               1               0                   0      
#>  2   0.1                             1               0.0776              0.00118
#>  3   0.2                             1               0.151               0.00461
#>  4   0.3                             1               0.219               0.0102 
#>  5   0.4                             1               0.284               0.0177 
#>  6   0.5                             1               0.344               0.0271 
#>  7   0.6                             1               0.400               0.0382 
#>  8   0.7                             1               0.453               0.0509 
#>  9   0.8                             1               0.502               0.0651 
#> 10   0.9                             1               0.548               0.0806 
#> # ℹ 91 more rows
#> # ℹ abbreviated name: ¹​`model.matrix(~isp(x, df = 5))`[,"(Intercept)"]
#> # ℹ 1 more variable: `model.matrix(~isp(x, df = 5))`[4:6] <dbl>

Created on 2024-06-29 with reprex v2.1.0
This is, however, a 101x2 dataframe.  The spline features are somehow nested
bake(rec, new_data = data) %>% 
  dim
#> [1] 101   2

Created on 2024-06-29 with reprex v2.1.0
Is there a way I can use step_mutate or other tidymodels functions to get each feature as a column right out from the call to bake?

The short answer is no.
Long answer. Ideally you would only use step_mutate() for single column creation. If you want to create multiple columns at a time, then I would suggest that you go ahead and write your own custom step.
For this specific issue, if you are wanting isplines using the {splines2} package, then you can use step_spline_monotone() which does just that.
This also illustrates why step_mutate() isn't going to help here. Using splines like this should be a learned task, hence you need to save some information such that you can apply the same transformation to the new data.

Instead of dim, see what is the output of bake with str. This will tell you the data structure, not just its dimensions.
In the code below I ran your example and assigned bake's output to a variable b. You can see from str(b) that it's a data.frame with two columns, the 2nd being the model matrix. So extract that column with the standard $ or [[ operators.
bake(rec, new_data = data) -> b

str(b)
#> tibble [101 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ x                            : num [1:101] 0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 ...
#>  $ model.matrix(~isp(x, df = 5)): num [1:101, 1:6] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>   ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#>   .. ..$ : chr [1:101] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
#>   .. ..$ : chr [1:6] "(Intercept)" "isp(x, df = 5)1" "isp(x, df = 5)2" "isp(x, df = 5)3" ...
#>   ..- attr(*, "assign")= int [1:6] 0 1 1 1 1 1

# extract with '$'
b$`model.matrix(~isp(x, df = 5))` %>% head()
#>   (Intercept) isp(x, df = 5)1 isp(x, df = 5)2 isp(x, df = 5)3 isp(x, df = 5)4 isp(x, df = 5)5
#> 1           1      0.00000000      0.00000000      0.00000000        0.00e+00               0
#> 2           1      0.07763184      0.00117614      0.00000792        2.00e-08               0
#> 3           1      0.15065344      0.00461024      0.00006272        3.20e-07               0
#> 4           1      0.21925104      0.01016334      0.00020952        1.62e-06               0
#> 5           1      0.28360704      0.01769984      0.00049152        5.12e-06               0
#> 6           1      0.34390000      0.02708750      0.00095000        1.25e-05               0

# note the extractor function '[['
cbind(b[1L], b[[2L]]) %>% str()
#> 'data.frame':    101 obs. of  7 variables:
#>  $ x              : num  0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 ...
#>  $ (Intercept)    : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>  $ isp(x, df = 5)1: num  0 0.0776 0.1507 0.2193 0.2836 ...
#>  $ isp(x, df = 5)2: num  0 0.00118 0.00461 0.01016 0.0177 ...
#>  $ isp(x, df = 5)3: num  0.00 7.92e-06 6.27e-05 2.10e-04 4.92e-04 ...
#>  $ isp(x, df = 5)4: num  0.00 2.00e-08 3.20e-07 1.62e-06 5.12e-06 ...
#>  $ isp(x, df = 5)5: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

Created on 2024-06-29 with reprex v2.1.0
